# Disable add-ons in firefox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, add-on

I would like to disable add-ons in firefox using javascript.I see some similar questions but the answers does not work for me.

Comment: I think I speak for the internet when I say, `keep your hands off my add-ons`

Comment: Please provide what you have tried, how you wish this to be done and your reasons for doing so. I'd be tempted to say on the client side it isn't or shouldn't be possible, else sites would be able to disable ad-blockers.

Comment: `see some similar questions but the answers does not work for me` - link to one

Comment: @Jaromanda, not a problem, I'll just write an add-on to disable the scripts that are trying to disable my add-ons... wait...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - good luck, because then I'll write a script to disable the add-on that disables the scripts that ... where was I, my head hurts :p

Answer (score 2):

You can't just disable any arbitrary addon using JS.

If that were possible, *any* ad service or website that displays ads would shut down plugins like adblock.
Interfering with a user's browser like that isn't possible. The level of access required would also open browsers up to all kinds of malicious content.

So, basically:

***What you want ain't possible.*** And for good reason.